# Transforming GPS coordinates for OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, gps, geolocation, openlayers

I am building a project in JavaScript that uses OpenLayers with an OpenStreetMap layer.

I have the coordinates "48.3185005, 14.2853003" (the coordinated of Linz, Austria) which I get from either navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() or the Google Maps Geocoding API.
Now I want to show this point on the map.

Which transformations are necessary for the map to display the correct location and how do I do these transformations with OpenLayers?
At the moment, I am always getting some point east of Africa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because OpenStreetMap data is a projected coordinate system, known as Web Mercator, ie, it is in meters, whereas your GPS data are in lat/lon. This is why all points appear to be in the sea off the West coast of Africa, as in a coordinate system covering the whole globe in meters, any coordinates in the range 180,180 and -90,90 will appear to be in that small area off the coast of Ghana. I notice in your original post you said East of Africa, but in a comment, you said Atlantic Ocean, from which I am assuming you meant West, which is consistent with my explanation. Is this correct?

You can deal with this in you map constructor by specifying a different map projection and display projection: see http://docs.openlayers.org/library/spherical_mercator.html

You want something along the lines of:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
  projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
  displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});
```

EPSG:3857 (originally 900913) is the official designation for Spherical Mercator and conversion between this and 4326 (lat/lon) is built into OpenLayers.

Comment: East of africa was when I tried some transformation I found online. Without transformations, it was the Atlantic Ocean. Thank you, it works now.

Answer (score 3):

This should set your map in the right location.

> map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(14.2853003,
>   48.3185005).transform('EPSG:4326', map.getProjectionObject()), 5);

You only need to know the input coordinate reference and use the getProjectObject function to get the target reference.

Comment: Well, it works already, but that function sure is nice for maintenance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

Would it simply be that you are mixing the values, the Point (14.2853003, 48.3185005) is in Yemen, and Point (48.3185005, 14.2853003) is in Austria..So check documentation whether the latitude & longitude values are given in different order than you think of

Comment: No, if I don't transform the coordinates, I am always in the Atlantic ocean (near Africa) on nearly the same place, even if I swap the coordinates. So it seems some kind of transformation is necessary.