# Baselayers with (probably) different projections

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

I am working with several types of baselayers (see code below):

1. An empty baseLayer
2. The basic WGS
3. Open Street Map
4. Google Terrain Map
5. Google Hybrid Map
6. Google Satellite Map

All of them can be switched and the tiles are visualized properly, there is no problem there.

The thing is: although 1 and 2 work just fine, when I switch to any of the other ones then all the other layers (inserted as geojson's with EPSG:4326 projection) are shown grouped in a single point of the screen, as if all of them had the same coordinates.

My guess is that there is some interference between EPSG:4326 and EPSG:900913 projections, but I am stuck at this point.

```js
function init(){

    map = new OpenLayers.Map( 'map' );
    var baseLayers = GetBaseLayers();
    map.addLayers(baseLayers);

    stateBordersText = //geojson ...
    stateBordersLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector('State borders'); 
    map.addLayer(stateBordersLayer);
    stateBordersLayer.addFeatures(geojson_format.read(stateBordersText));

    // etc ...

}

function GetBaseLayers(){

    emptyBaselayer = new OpenLayers.Layer("Empty BaseLayer", {isBaseLayer: true, displayInLayerSwitcher: true}); 
    defaultBaselayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("OpenLayers Basic", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'});

    var mapnik = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM();
    mapnik.transitionEffect = "resize";

    //Source: http://openlayers.org/blog/2010/07/10/google-maps-v3-for-openlayers/
    var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Physical",{type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN});
    var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Streets",{numZoomLevels: 22});
    var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google("Google Satellite",{type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,sphericalMercator:true,numZoomLevels:22,layers: 'basic'});

    var baseLayers = [emptyBaselayer,defaultBaselayer,mapnik,gphy,gmap,gsat];

    return baseLayers;

}
```

Comment: Check out this answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428170/tranforming-gps-coordinates-for-openlayers/23441569#23441569. You are correct, 4326 is in degrees and 900913 (now known as 3857) is in meters, so you need to convert from one to the other, otherwise all the 4326 will appear off the coast of West Africa, as 3857 spans thousands of meters East/West and North/South, so any point in lat/lon will appear to be in a bunch at 0,0.

Comment: Thanks John. "will appear off the coast of West Africa": this is indeed the case. But my struggle here is to make compatible the base layers 1 and 2 (EPSG:4326 projection) with 3, 4, 5 and 6 (EPSG:900913). I could maybe sacrifice #2 (openlayer's basic WGS), but in any case I would be in need of a blank baselayer in EPSG:900913 for my project. I am going to try to work this angle...

Comment: If it is vector, you can translate the coordinates. If you are talking about tiles, you can not mix 4326 and 3857, period.

Comment: I thought so, but I wanted to confirm. Thanks a lot. In this case what I am trying to do right now is trying to set this custom blank base layer `emptyBaselayer = new OpenLayers.Layer("Empty BaseLayer", {isBaseLayer: true, displayInLayerSwitcher: true}); ` as EPSG:900913. My guess is `emptyBaselayer = new OpenLayers.Layer("Empty BaseLayer", {isBaseLayer: true, displayInLayerSwitcher: true, sphericalMercator: true});`, although currently I am not able to make the basic google tiles work (weird, since I have previous custom wourking code that I built myself..). Cheers.

Comment: Now that all google layers are working _(the problem was that my geojson's were not reprojected to Shperical Mercator)_, my empty base layer does not work. Neither does OpenLayers.Layer.OSM, which I doesn't . So I went from panel #3 to panel #4: http://www.sandraandwoo.com/comics/2012-11-19-0430-software-engineering-now-with-cats.png . Damn it.

Comment: The reprojection was what I suggested in the first link :D

Comment: In fact, my code makes no difference between this: `map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {projection: wgsProjection, displayProjection: sphMercProjection});` and this `map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {projection: wgsProjection});`. I had to transform all the geojsons through `geojson_format = new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({'internalProjection': sphMercProjection,'externalProjection': wgsProjection});` and oly then it worked. Though `OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()` doesn't seem to work, which seems to indicate I f*cked up somewhere.. but my main interest right now is making the empty base layer work.

Comment: damn it, I reversed them... great. `map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {projection: sphMercProjection, displayProjection: wgsProjection});`. I am really sorry, I have to deal with too many codes at the same time. The `new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON` projection specification was still necessary though. Now the empty layer kind of works (with some slightly weird behavior... too long to be described). Not `OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()` though.